# How to define the input layer in (spiking) neural network with Pytorch

Tags: python, input, neural-network, pytorch

I have recently started working with Python and more specifically with the Pitorch library  in order to create a neural network. I am working with Spiking Neural Network  (SNN) but I suspect that the way to define an Artificial Neural Network (ANN) and a SNN is very similar, being the only change that you have to specify the type of neuron.

In the typical examples with MNIST dataset the neural network is defined:

```
net = nn.Sequential(
nn.Flatten(),
nn.Linear(28*28, 10, bias=False),  
neuron.LIFNode(tau=tau)
)
```

Being the last line of the code to define that is a SNN. The problem here is that I am not very related with images problems and I am not sure about what is the exact meaning of the first hyperparameter ("28 * 28") of the line of code `nn.Linear(28*28, 10, bias=False)`. I do not know whether that means that you have 28 neurons and in each neuron you introduce 28 points per sample or that the input layer is like a matrix of 28*28 where you only introduce a point per sample or the input layer is based on 784 neurons (the multiplication of 28 by 28).

I am trying to face a regression task problem where my train dataset is based on 4096 samples and in each sample I have 64 points. So, my querie is how to introduce this input because I only want a single input neuron where I can introduce 64 points per sample.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html?highlight=linear#torch.nn.Linear), the first parameter of `nn.Linear` is the dimension of the input that will go through this layer, and the second parameter is the size of the ouput (which you can also call the number of neurons).

Here the first parameter is `28*28` probably because the input given to the `nn.Sequential` network are images of shape 28x28, and the `nn.Flatten` turns them into vectors of size `28*28`.

For your task, you should get rid of the `nn.Flatten` layer if your samples are already one-dimensional, and you should use `nn.Linear(64, 1)` if you really want to use only one neuron.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer. I have been looking at examples and if you put `nn.Linear(64,1)`  , what you create is 64 input neurons and one output neuron, having 64 weights and I only want 1, that's why my doubt. I do not know whether `nn.Linear(1*64,1)` would be correct or not.

Comment: [link](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Python_PyTorch_nn_Linear_01.html)  Here there are a couple of examples.

Comment: If your sample has dimension 64, and you want to use every point in it, your need to have  at least the 64 weights in order to combine information from all points. This is more like having one neuron which has 64 synapses ready to take in your data, and one synapse to give its output.

Comment: I have been thinking about what you said and I understand what you are saying, but I still don't understand what is the meaning of the hyperparameter 28 * 28. Because you said that "... turns them into vectors of size 28*28", so in `nn.Linear(28x28,10)` what is that 28 * 28? 28 neurons and in each neuron a vector of size 28 is introduced??

Comment: 28*28=784 is simply the number of input synapses that the one neuron will have. Since in a 28 by 28 vectors there are 28*28 values, when flattened it gives a 28*28=784-sized vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!!! I understand what you are saying!